# How to purify the output of created structured json file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I learned how to create structured json file from csv file that generated from google form. However, produced json object contains time header because google form generates that and it saved to csv before creating json object from it.

Here is what I tried to solve this:

```js
let inputCsv = `"Timestamp","Enter First Name:","Enter Middle Initial","Enter Last Name:","Enter UIN:","Are you attending the event?"
"2019/02/22 12:41:56 PM CST","Jonathan","Samson,"Rowe","670168228","No"
"2019/02/22 12:44:56 PM CST","Phil","Aspilla","beltran","6689144343","Yes"`

function convertToJson(inputCsv) { 
  //inputCsv passed from readfile function
  /* Split input string by `,` and clean up each item */

  var lines = inputCsv.split('\n');
  lines.splice(0,1);

  var arrayCsv = [];
  for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
      const lineArray = lines[line].split(',').map(s => s.replace(/"/gi, '').trim());
      lineArray.splice(0,1);

      arrayCsv[line] = lineArray;
  }


  const outputJson = [];

  console.log(arrayCsv);
}

convertToJson(inputCsv)
```

basically I want to get rid of extra time header (like `2019/02/22 12:41:56 PM CST) every line of  input csv file when I create structured json object from it, so here is my desired output:

**update: desired output json file**

```
[{
    "uin": "123456789",
    "studentInfo": {
         "firstName": "Jonathan",
         "middleName": "Samson",
         "lastName": "Rowe",
         "rsvpStatus": "Yes"
    }
 },
 {
    "uin": "123456788",
    "studentInfo": {
         "firstName": "phil",
         "middleName": "Aspilla",
         "lastName": "beltran",
         "rsvpStatus": "No"
    }
 }]
```

I am not sure how regular expression works in javascript and I want to produce clean structured json object from csv that comes from google form. How can I make this happen? Any way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Don't use regex. Inside your map method you'll need to create and return the desired structure for each row. You could pull the object keys from the header row if you didn't want to hard code them.

Comment: your code is already `splicing` the first element ? what is your exact question ?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I may have multiple lines to write them in json, so better to programmatically get rid of extra time header that shouldn't be in json.

Comment: @CodeManiac my code is just my attempt not sure that is correct. I tested that part of code but didn't produce my expected output anyway. Any thoughts?

Comment: @beyond_inifinity you need to create object in desired format and than push it to array. btw i am not sure on what basis you're taking keys, name uin and studentinfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build object in desired format and than push in array.

```js
let inputCsv = `"Timestamp","Enter First Name:","Enter Middle Initial","Enter Last Name:","Enter UIN:","Are you attending the event?"
"2019/02/22 12:41:56 PM CST","Christ","A","coda","670168228","No"
"2019/02/22 12:44:56 PM CST","jack","NA","Harvey","6689144343","Yes"`

function convertToJson(inputCsv) { 
  const keyMapping = {
    "\"Enter First Name:\"" : 'firstName',
    "\"Enter Middle Initial\"": 'middleName',
    "\"Enter Last Name:\"": 'lastName',
    "\"Enter UIN:\"":'uin',
    "\"Are you attending the event?\"":'rsvp'
  }
  var lines = inputCsv.split('\n');
  let [keys] = lines
  keys = keys.split(',').splice(1,)
  lines.splice(0,1);
  
  var arrayCsv = [];
  for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
  const lineArray = lines[line].split(',').splice(1,).reduce((o,s,i) =>((o[keyMapping[keys[i]]] = s.replace(/"/gi, '').trim()),o),{});

// here i am creating object in desired format

      let obj = {uin:lineArray['uin'],studentInfo:{firstName:lineArray}}

      arrayCsv[line] = obj;
  }


  const outputJson = [];

  console.log(arrayCsv);
}

convertToJson(inputCsv)
```

Comment: I made mistake when I typed my desired output, plus, if I have multiple lines, so how can I clean the line and get desired json from it?

Comment: @beyond_inifinity in this case it turns out to be completely different question that your original one.instead of array you can actually build a object with key/value pair.

Comment: I mistakenly put wrong desired output, now how can I get my desired json by cleaning time header in every line of input csv? can you provide workable solution if it is possible? Thanks